# Is there any correct format for Xpath search?

Tags: java, html, selenium-webdriver, xpath, format

So I have been in QA Test automation recently using Selenium. When I select/write the Xpath for an element, it seems that there are different format meaning that it can be done in different ways. For example

```
protected final String LOGIN_BUTTON_LOCATOR = "//i[contains(@class,'sign-in')]";
```

and

```
protected final String ERROR_MESSAGE_LOCATOR = "//div[@class='flash error' and @id='flash']";
```

As you see above, the class name is written in a different format. Both work for me now, but is there any way that is preferred more over another?

Comment: There are an infinite number of ways of writing an Xpath. You want your Xpath to be as simple as possible. Your first locator depends on a single element, your second one depends on two. Either of those two classes could change at any second and break your selector, making it twice as likely to break.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be that "find all the students called 'Jim'" and "find all the students who got an 'A' grade" have the same answer, but they are completely different questions, and asking which of the two questions is "correct" or "preferred" is meaningless. You have given us two completely different XPath expressions and asked which is better - we can only say the one that is better is the one that correctly reflects your intent.

Note that @class="x" tests whether the value of the class attribute is exactly equal to "x", whereas `contains(@class, 'x')` tests whether it contains "x" as a substring. Using `contains` where you meant `=` is a common mistake, but it's not wrong if matching a substring is what you intended.

Comment: so there is no wrong as long as XPath find its element whether it is a @class="x" or contains(@class, 'x').  It's all relative in one way or another. got it

Comment: There are two main roles for Selenium, one is for test assertions, the other is for screen scraping. In the first case, the "best" XPath is the one that rejects as many invalid documents as possible. In the second case, the "best" XPath is the one that makes as few assumptions about the data as possible. So in both cases there are good solutions and bad solutions: it all depends what you are trying to achieve.